# How to change template with vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am a beginner of `vue.js`, now I try to set up a website with dynamic tab.
I have some problem when changing different tab with different template.

But I face a problem, when I click the `ul` element in my website to change another template, it shows error as following:
[image]

It seems like template included error.

```html
    <template id="switchhover">
     <div>
       <div class="menu">
          <div class="title">
            <img src="../assets/title.jpg" class="min_picture">
            <span>Hello</span>
          </div>
           <ul>
            <li @click="changeView('Home')" class="liststyle">Home(首頁)</li>
            <li @click="changeView('WorkExperience')" class="liststyle">Work Experience(工作經歷)</li>
            <li class="liststyle">Project Experience(專案經歷)</li>
            <li class="liststyle">Portfolio(作品集)</li>
            <li class="liststyle">Photo(相片)</li>
            <li class="liststyle">
              <router-link :to="{path: '/'}">Back to Navigation Page<br>(回導覽頁)
              </router-link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        <div class="link">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100001824960776">
              <div class="fb"></div>
            </a>
            <a href="https://github.com/PefyLi">
              <div class="github"></div>
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/grant-li-3a6680150/">
              <div class="linkedin"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="content">
            <div class="banner">
              <div>
               <div class="picture">
                 <img src="../assets/title.jpg" class="bar_picture">
               </div>
               <div>
                  <span style="font-size:35px;margin-right:29px">Hello</span>
                    <span>Hello</span><br><br><br><br>
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>
             <component :is="currentTab" keep-alive></component>
        </div>
       </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    import Home from './Home';
    import WorkExperience from './WorkExperience';

    export default {
          data(){
            return{
               currentTab:Home
             }
          },

           methods:{
            changeView: function(viewName) {
              this.currentTab = viewName
            }
          },
          components: {
            Home:{ template: Home},
            WorkExperience:{ template: WorkExperience}
          },
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: what looks odd at first glance ... the initial value of `currentTab` is an `Object` (I presume) you import from `./Home` ... but `changeView` function sets the value to a `String` - seems like that's not *quite right*

Comment: I found my bug. Because I made object to string, the view couldn't show. You are correct :)